# Shared Doc Always Opens to A Certain Position/Page. Can it be changed?

Tags: google-docs

When opening a shared Google Doc, it always opens to the same spot, which is not the beginning... is there some kind of formatting tag here (that can be changed) so it opens at the beginning (or at some other point)?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please add a brief descriptiono of the steps that you follow to open the shared doc. Are you clicking on a link sent in email or chat message? Have you tried to open them from Google Drive of Google Docs instead of clicking a link?

Comment: I hadn't tried different methods of opening it... will try and report back, thanks Rubén.